How to make Surefire run a test passed with -Dtest flag, only if it's included
I have pom.xml, where I have defined different profiles for Test Suites:
<profile>
        <id>profile-a-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/ATestSuite**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

That test suite looks like that in code:
@Suite
@SuiteDisplayName("A test suite")
@SelectPackages("com.mypackage.tests")
@IncludeTags(INCLUDE)
@ExcludeTags(EXCLUDE)
class ATestSuite

Now in Jenkins I want to pass a set of flaky tests with the following Maven Command:
mvn test -P profile-a-tests -Dtest=SOME_FLAKY_TEST

However, when the build is running, even if SOME_FLAKY_TEST in not in ATestSuite it gets executed regardless, and I want to execute only if it's included in the Surefire includes definition. Does -Dtest override Surefire's includes/excludes definition, and if so, how can I achieve only running tests passed with mvn and not others.

First why are you using such an old version of maven-surefire-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) at the moment 3.5.0 ... second why using profiles for suites? If you like to select particular tests that can be achieved by using -Dtest=TestCircle etc.

On the last part with selecting the particular test. If I pass -Dtest=TestCircle it will run the test even if it's not in the the  for maven surefire, and I don't want that behavior.

I recommend to ignore the include part... because usually you don't define include... follow the defaults... meaning the naming convention for unit- and integration tests (unit test *Test* details https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) .. furthermore why even using suites.. which has to be maintained manually.. The much more better way is to identify why those tests are flaky and fix them... may those tests are integration tests and not unit tests...

BTW: Where are those @IncludeTags and @ExcludeTags(EXCLUDE) annotations coming from?
